# Applying default values if a node does not exist

Tags: xml, xslt

I am currently using this construct to assign default values if a node does not exist in a supplied XML doc. Is there a more concise way of stating the same thing?

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="var_name"><xsl:value-of select="var_name"/></xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>default</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: This is an untested suggestion but I guess the XPath selector understands "or": `<xsl:value-of select="var_name or 'default'"/>`

Comment: Doesn't work, I'm afraid. It just returns true, rather than the value of var_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I. XPath 2.0**

**Use**:

```
concat($yourVar, 'default'[not($yourVar)])
```

**Here is a complete XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="yourVar" select="'something'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="yourVar2" select="''"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="concat($yourVar, 'default'[not($yourVar)])"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:sequence select="concat($yourVar2, 'default'[not($yourVar2)])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted strings are produced and output for both variables**:

```
something
default
```

---

**II. XPath 1.0**

**Use**:

```
concat($yourNodeExpr, 
       substring('default', 1 + 7*boolean($yourNodeExpr)))
```

This produces the string value of `$yourNodeExpr` if it contains at least one node, otherwise it produces the string `"default"`.

**Explanation**:

We use the fact that:

In XPath 1.0 whenever a boolean value is an operand of an arithmetic operator, this value is converted to a number: `number(false()) = 0` and `number(true()) = 1`. Thus, if `boolean($yourNodeExpr)` is `true()` the second argumend to `substring above will become`1+7 = 8` and the substring will be the empty string.

On the other side, if `boolean($yourNodeExpr)` is `false()`, the second argument to `substring()` is `1+0 = 1` and the substring is the string `"default"`

**A more general expression**:

```
concat(substring($val1, 1 div $cond1),
       substring($val1, 1 div $cond2)
       )
```

Assuming that the the two conditions `$cond1` and `$cond2` are *mutually exclusive* (`($cond1 and $cond2) = false()` and `($cond1 or $cond2) = true()` ) then **the above expression produces the string `$val1` when `$cond1` is `true()` and produces the string `$val2` when `$cond2` is `true()`.**

Comment: While that solution works, it's very non-intuitive. To be honest I was basically looking for an equivalent to bash variable substition: `${parameter-default}`

Comment: @rohl: If you need intuitive solution, use XPath 2.0 and up.

Comment: @rohl: The XPath 2.0 expression I added to this answer is most probably what you are after.

Comment: really impressive xpath 1.0 trick (+1). @rohl if you need intuitive 1.0 solution, embed Dimitre's code within a parametric function.

Comment: @empo: Thanks. And you probably mean *named template* -- in XSLT 1.0 there is no `xsl:function`